# Is it possible to share data between native C++ modules?

Tags: android, c++

I am have this Android project that contains 2 native c++ modules. Module A and Module B. Now, I module A is a recording interface and a wrapper to communicate with the Java modules via JNI calls and module B process the data collected by module A. I was wondering if it was possible to directly share data between A and B. Module A already listed module B as a dependency but still cannot seem to find a way to establish data sharing between the 2. All the examples I have seen is communicating Java with Native but no 2 native modules in the same project. If it is at all possible or anybody has any ideas, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking into different ways of IPC in Linux environment, this is a very broad topic, not suited for a single SO question.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to share data between native C++ modules?" - Yes, of course.

You have many options. Here are *some* of them:

- Share data using global variables (usually not the greatest idea)
- Share data using shared memory
- Share data using files
- Share data using sockets (Unix domain sockets, TCP sockets, whatever)

There are a *ton* of ways to share data. Which one is appropriate depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's hard to share data through global variables on two independent modules :)

Comment: @SergeyA Not if they are loaded into the same process.. But in any case; usually a bad way to go.

Comment: I am not really familiar how Android does it, but I was thinking about two independent processes. I am honestly not clear of what referred as *module* on Android platform.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sockets, each submodule listening and pushing data to a specific port. This is the most basic way, maybe there is a higher level solution.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It solves the problem, so it is an answer.